# Directly call unexported native wmain function from C#

Tags: c#, pinvoke, program-entry-point, dllexport

Is it possible on windows to directly call the native exe main entrypoint (wmain) from other process, without the wmain being marked as dllexport?

**Background**
Our .NET app needs to call 3rd party native .exe that then loads and calls our native .dll. We need to pump large amount of data into the process (via the native .dll) and so I'm investigating possibility of direct memory access (as compared to setting up a shared memory between the two processes - .net and native - and copying the memory back and forth).
I was trying to P/Invoke wmain, but failed with EntryPointNotFoundException as it is not dllexported (I cannot see it in dumpbin exports). Though it's not dllexported. it still needs to be exported in some way for the OS to call - so can I somehow use this to call the main directly?

**Edit1:**
I found a short PE loader code here: http://www.cultdeadcow.com/tools/peload/peloader.c and through some experiments it seems it might be usable. However this gots pretty involved and fragile (realies on undocumented behavior of OS loading PE). So I'm already investigating other means of achieving my goal (including simple IPC, remote thread injection etc.)

Comment: That's not how it works. wmain is not exported. It does not need to be exported. The linker creates an executable with pe meta data identifying the entry point. The RTL code then does startup and calls wmain. You won't be able to pinvoke a different process. Pinvoke is for inproc calls. I think you'll need to do a lot of learning before you make much progress.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to load an EXE as if it was a DLL... at least not using standard well documented code.

Comment: binaries can have distinct memory model and invocation model defined in the PE header and how the code was compiled/linked that is set up when the EXE is executed.  Loading it like a DLL (if you even could) would likely be extremely problematic.